# php and json decoding links stop working

Tags: php, json, php-curl

hi I have a small problem i need help with i have a web page that outputs live streams in json format with links looking like this

```
rtmp:\/\/server:port\/camera1.stream
```

now if I copy and past that link into notepad and change the `\/` to `/` my self, the links plays fine in every media player I have and I can see the camera feed but when I use a php script to decode the json output the streams do not play at all when outputed by echo or when added to a genarated m3u8 file :

bellow is the code i use to get the page and json decode

```
$stream_id = $_GET["cam"];
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();
//set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ip:port/json");
//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
//close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);  
$response = json_decode($output), true);

foreach ($response['cameras'] as $result) {
    if($result['name'] == $stream_id){
        echo $result['cam_stream'];
    }
}
```

Comment: if you printout $output and $response, are they identical

Comment: I wonder how does this work ? `$response = json_decode($output), true);` That should normally result in a `PARSE_ERROR`.

Comment: Do you try to dump the content of `$output` using `var_dump` for example ?